# While reading a csv file in java using bufferReader, getting output is not understandable format

Tags: java, csv

```
   public static void getDataFromCSV(String name,String colName) throws Exception { 
        url = workingDirectory+"\\src\\main\\resources\\dataset\\icx-catalog.csv";
        
        String columnName = null;
        boolean found=false;
        

        parser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(url),"utf-8"));
        String line="";
        parser.readLine();
        while ((line= parser.readLine() )!=null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            
        }
}
```

I got output as �d�[�������Sz!)�`J�(������-�aX6�B2ۢRz��p��B2�b3,7��KAjI_�%��B2�rRz!�z�ʰ��^xL�6�,�����P5�x!<0&{ʔ^�
�y�ͺ���,�o����B\e�WU��|M���,Zs^�?�B�\�N��ݝx�z���P�P^��;/3�0_���.�$E���B��4��9�Wv�r^�_��^�a����u�P56^���}�pM60�����a>,>��

Comment: Perhaps, the file is not UTF-8-encoded?

Comment: @fluffy do you have any idea on how to decode the above format